# How to change Trac IK parameters online

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to know how to change the IK parameters in C++. The `kinematics.yaml` contains default parameters and I would like to change for certain planning operations the `solve_type` parameters.

So how to retrieve the IK solver pointer in order to change some parameters, and so that it is updated for the MoveGroupInterface?

I am using the TRAC-IK plugin if it matters.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365697/how-to-change-trac-ik-parameters-online/) by [cv_ros_user](https://answers.ros.org/users/44640/cv_ros_user/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-11-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-16**:\

> I am using the TRAC-IK plugin if it matters.

Yes, this matters, as only Trac IK uses the `solve_type` parameter.

I've updated the title of your question to mention your use of Trac IK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The `kinematics.yaml` contains default parameters and I would like to change for certain planning operations the `solve_type` parameters.

I don't believe this will work. That file is only read once, during startup (of `roslaunch` actually).

MoveIt instantiates the IK solver then *once* (well: depending on how many groups you have configured of course), which reads the parameters, *once*, and those get used until a new Trac IK instance is created.

This is the only time `TRAC_IKKinematicsPlugin` (ie: the plugin class) reads that parameter: [link](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/src/eb11e334494afbd8ca624948b3570637c668a209/trac_ik_kinematics_plugin/src/trac_ik_kinematics_plugin.cpp#lines-147).

> So how to retrieve the IK solver pointer in order to change some parameters, and so that it is updated for the MoveGroupInterface?

Internally, Trac IK stores the value of that parameter in a private member variable called `solve_type_` ([here](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/src/eb11e334494afbd8ca624948b3570637c668a209/trac_ik_kinematics_plugin/include/trac_ik/trac_ik_kinematics_plugin.hpp#lines-53)). There doesn't appear to be any setter (nor a getter) for that member variable.

So even with a reference to the IK solver's instance, you would not be able to change the value of that member variable.

---

Having written that: the plugin *does* check how it's been configured *before* solving a query ([here](https://bitbucket.org/traclabs/trac_ik/src/eb11e334494afbd8ca624948b3570637c668a209/trac_ik_kinematics_plugin/src/trac_ik_kinematics_plugin.cpp#lines-359:372)).

So theoretically, you *could* add [dynamic_reconfigure](https://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure) support to the MoveIt plugin, expose that `solve_type_` member as a `dynamic_reconfigure` variable, and then use `dynamic_reconfigure`'s service API to update the solve type dynamically. Note: you'd still need to add a setter though.

It would not be linked to any particular query though, as it wouldn't be part of the IK request. But it would allow you to change the solve type *after* the MoveIt IK plugin has been instantiated.

---

Edit:

> I want to change this parameters in the code and without user intervention.

`dynamic_reconfigure` has a service interface which is non-user-facing. It's exactly there to be used "from code". It does not require any user interaction.

> Any advices about how could I maybe dynamically cast it to a "TRAC-IK solver" in oder to set this parameter?

Without creating that setter you'll not be able to change anything.

But if you're willing to do all sorts of nasty things, then:

- add the setter
- downcast the reference to the specific `TRAC_IKKinematicsPlugin`
- use the setter

It would be *very* brittle though, as you'd have to be sure what you have is actually an instance of `TRAC_IKKinematicsPlugin`.

And using `dynamic_cast` this way is not what most people consider *proper* use.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cv_ros_user](https://answers.ros.org/users/44640/cv_ros_user/) on 2020-11-16**:
Thanks for your answer.

I don't think `dynamic_reconfigure` is an option for me. I want to change this parameters in the code and without user intervention. I would like to try something like move to a specific pose that should maximize the manipulability index and then use Cartesian plan with distance criterion for the IK solver.

I am already building MoveIt and TRAC-IK from sources. I have seen this line: `const kinematics::KinematicsBaseConstPtr& solver = jmg->getSolverInstance();` ([here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/ff552bf861609f99ca97a7e173fcbeb0c03e9f45/moveit_core/robot_state/src/robot_state.cpp#L1497)). Any advices about how could I maybe dynamically cast it to a "TRAC-IK solver" in oder to set this parameter?

**Comment by [cv_ros_user](https://answers.ros.org/users/44640/cv_ros_user/) on 2020-11-16**:
Thanks again.

I have almost no experience with `dynamic_reconfigure` so I didn't know it was possible to use it with services. I will try to expose this parameter. The concept of plugin in MoveIt is a little bit hard to grasp for me. So I tend to avoid this path.

**Comment by [cv_ros_user](https://answers.ros.org/users/44640/cv_ros_user/) on 2020-11-17**:
So I have added a `trac_ik/trac_ik_kinematics_plugin/cfg/TRACIKDynamicReconfigure.cfg` file. I have added a `dynamic_reconfigure_server_` in `trac_ik/trac_ik_kinematics_plugin/src/trac_ik_kinematics_plugin.cpp`.

When using `rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure`, change is correctly printed in `TRAC_IKKinematicsPlugin::dynamicReconfigureCallback`.

But I have this kind of errors `Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/ik/trac_ik/set_parameters]` at initialisation. So in which files should I put the `cfg` and the `dynamic_reconfigure_server_` in order to update correctly the `TRAC_IKKinematicsPlugin`?